Capacitive sensor FDC2114 using STM32F407. I wrote code and it seems alright but I don't get answer
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "i2c.h"
#include "usart.h"
#include "gpio.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FDC2114_I2C_ADDR_0                  0x2B      // I2C address of the FDC2114
#define FDC2114_DEVICE_ID                   0x7F      // FDC2114 Device ID
#define FDC2114_CONFIG                      0x1A
#define FDC2114_MUX_CONFIG                  0x1B
#define FDC2214_STATUS                      0x18
#define FDC2114_ERROR_CONFIG                0x19

#define FDC2114_DATA_CH0_MSB                  0x00
#define FDC2114_DATA_CH0_LSB                    0x01
#define FDC2114_DATA_CH1_MSB                  0x02
#define FDC2114_DATA_CH1_LSB                    0x03
#define FDC2114_DATA_CH2_MSB                  0x04
#define FDC2114_DATA_CH2_LSB                    0x05
#define FDC2114_DATA_CH3_MSB                  0x06
#define FDC2114_DATA_CH3_LSB                    0x07

#define FDC2114_RCOUNT_CH0                      0x08
#define FDC2114_RCOUNT_CH1                      0x09
#define FDC2114_RCOUNT_CH2                      0x0A
#define FDC2114_RCOUNT_CH3                      0x0B

#define FDC2114_OFFSET_CH0                    0x0C
#define FDC2114_OFFSET_CH1                  0x0D
#define FDC2114_OFFSET_CH2                  0x0E
#define FDC2114_OFFSET_CH3                  0x0F

#define FDC2114_SETTLECOUNT_CH0                 0x10
#define FDC2114_SETTLECOUNT_CH1                 0x11
#define FDC2114_SETTLECOUNT_CH2                 0x12
#define FDC2114_SETTLECOUNT_CH3                 0x13

#define FDC2114_CLOCK_DIVIDERS_CH0          0x14
#define FDC2114_CLOCK_DIVIDERS_CH1          0x15
#define FDC2114_CLOCK_DIVIDERS_CH2          0x16
#define FDC2114_CLOCK_DIVIDERS_CH3          0x17



#define FDC2114_DRIVE_CH0                   0x1E
#define FDC2114_DRIVE_CH1                   0x1F
#define FDC2114_DRIVE_CH2                   0x20
#define FDC2114_DRIVE_CH3                   0x21

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
void FDC2114_WriteRegister(uint8_t reg, uint16_t value)
{
    uint8_t data[3];
    data[0] = reg;
    data[1] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF; // MSB
    data[2] = value & 0xFF;        // LSB

    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, FDC2114_I2C_ADDR_0 << 1, data, 3, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}



void FDC2114_Init(void)

{
      // Check Device ID (0x3054 for FDC2114)
      uint16_t Device_ID_value = 0x3054;
      FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_DEVICE_ID , Device_ID_value);
    
    
    //Configuration for CONFIG register (0x1A)
    uint16_t config_value = 0x1681; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_CONFIG , config_value);

    // Configuration for MUX_CONFIG register (0x1B)
    uint16_t mux_config_value = 0xC209; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_MUX_CONFIG, mux_config_value);
    
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    
      // Configuration for RCOUNT_CH0 register (0x08)
    uint16_t RCOUNT_CH0_value = 0x8329; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_RCOUNT_CH0, RCOUNT_CH0_value);
    
      // Configuration for RCOUNT_CH1 register (0x09)
    uint16_t RCOUNT_CH1_value = 0x8329; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_RCOUNT_CH1, RCOUNT_CH1_value);
    
      // Configuration for RCOUNT_CH2 register (0x0A)
    uint16_t RCOUNT_CH2_value = 0x8329; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_RCOUNT_CH2, RCOUNT_CH2_value);
    
      // Configuration for RCOUNT_CH3 register (0x0B)
    uint16_t RCOUNT_CH3_value = 0x8329; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_RCOUNT_CH3, RCOUNT_CH3_value); 
        
        
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        
        
        // Configuration for SETTLECOUNT_CH0 register (0x10)
    uint16_t SETTLECOUNT_CH0_value = 0x000A; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_SETTLECOUNT_CH0,SETTLECOUNT_CH0_value);
        
        // Configuration for SETTLECOUNT_CH1 register (0x11)
    uint16_t SETTLECOUNT_CH1_value = 0x000A; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_SETTLECOUNT_CH1, SETTLECOUNT_CH1_value);
        
        // Configuration for SETTLECOUNT_CH2 register (0x12)
    uint16_t SETTLECOUNT_CH2_value = 0x000A; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_SETTLECOUNT_CH2, SETTLECOUNT_CH2_value);
        
        // Configuration for SETTLECOUNT_CH3 register (0x13)
    uint16_t SETTLECOUNT_CH3_value = 0x000A; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_SETTLECOUNT_CH3, SETTLECOUNT_CH3_value);
        
        
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        
        
        // Configuration for CLOCK_DIVIDER_CH0 register (0x14)
    uint16_t CLOCK_DIVIDER_CH0_value = 0x2002; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_CLOCK_DIVIDERS_CH0, CLOCK_DIVIDER_CH0_value);
        
        // Configuration for CLOCK_DIVIDER_CH1 register (0x15)
    uint16_t CLOCK_DIVIDER_CH1_value = 0x2002; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_CLOCK_DIVIDERS_CH1, CLOCK_DIVIDER_CH1_value);
        
        // Configuration for CLOCK_DIVIDER_CH2 register (0x16)
    uint16_t CLOCK_DIVIDER_CH2_value = 0x2002; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_CLOCK_DIVIDERS_CH2, CLOCK_DIVIDER_CH2_value);
        
        // Configuration for CLOCK_DIVIDER_CH3 register (0x17)
    uint16_t CLOCK_DIVIDER_CH3_value = 0x2002; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_CLOCK_DIVIDERS_CH3, CLOCK_DIVIDER_CH3_value);
        
        
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        
        
        // Configuration for ERROR_CONFIG register (0x19)
    uint16_t ERROR_CONFIG_value = 0x0001; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(0x19, ERROR_CONFIG_value);
        
        
        
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        
        // Configuration for DRIVE_CURRENT_CH0 register (0x1E)
    uint16_t DRIVE_CURRENT_CH0_value = 0x7C00; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_DRIVE_CH0, DRIVE_CURRENT_CH0_value);
        
        // Configuration for DRIVE_CURRENT_CH1 register (0x1F)
    uint16_t DRIVE_CURRENT_CH1_value = 0x7C00; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_DRIVE_CH1, DRIVE_CURRENT_CH1_value);
        
        // Configuration for DRIVE_CURRENT_CH2 register (0x20)
    uint16_t DRIVE_CURRENT_CH2_value = 0x7C00; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_DRIVE_CH2, DRIVE_CURRENT_CH2_value);
        
        // Configuration for DRIVE_CURRENT_CH3 register (0x21)
    uint16_t DRIVE_CURRENT_CH3_value = 0x7C00; // 
    FDC2114_WriteRegister(FDC2114_DRIVE_CH3, DRIVE_CURRENT_CH3_value);
        
  
}

uint16_t FDC2114_Read_Channel_0(void)
{
    uint8_t data[2];
    uint16_t channel_0_data;

    // Register address for CH0 DATA
    uint8_t reg_addr = FDC2114_DATA_CH0_MSB; // Replace with register address of other channels

    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, FDC2114_I2C_ADDR_0 << 1, &reg_addr, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, FDC2114_I2C_ADDR_0 << 1, data, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

    channel_0_data = (data[0] << 8) | data[1];

    return channel_0_data;
}

void UART_Transmit(uint16_t data)
{
    char buffer[10];
    sprintf(buffer, "%u\r\n", data);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*)buffer, strlen(buffer), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}


/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  FDC2114_Init();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
    
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
       uint16_t channel_0_data = FDC2114_Read_Channel_0();
       UART_Transmit(channel_0_data);
       HAL_Delay(50); 
        
           
        

    
    

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  //if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  //{
  //  Error_Handler();
  //}

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  //if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
 // {
  //  Error_Handler();
 // }
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */


I think you'll find better help is an embedded sub than here.

I edited the question to format the code to improve readability, but after doing that realised the question body only contains code. Therefore, it isn't obvious what you are seeking help with. Also, the USER CODE BEGIN and USER CODE END suggest part of the code has been automatically generated by a tool, so again not sure part of the code you want help with.

I don't get answer is meaningless ... please explain what you mean by that ... explain what you get, not what you don't get

Of course it does not work. You are trying to communicate to the chip using I2C1 peripheral before you initialize I2C1 peripheral.
The next thing it might not work is the fact that you are doing the read in two separate phases with I2C stop condition between register address write and data read phases. Not all chips support that kind of protocol, and it's not the protocol given in the data sheet. However, some chips do support it even if they specifically don't mention it.
